# Randomly missing images in IE when using jQuery Masonry

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

I am working on a web page that renders a photo wall, and as you scroll down, it uses jQuery infinite scroll to load in the next batch of photos.

I am using [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) along with [jQuery InfiniteScroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/).

All is working fine under Chrome and Firefox, but when viewing under IE, I noticed that the images would randomly fail to show, though if I refreshed the page, they would appear but others would go missing. Likewise, if I click the right mouse button on the missing image and choose 'Show Picture' it immediately appears.

So I tested a couple of the demos on the [jQuery Masonry website](http://masonry.desandro.com/), and found that again, whilst under IE, occasionally, random images would not render. This happens for me on the [Infinite Scroll demo](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/infinite-scroll.html), and even the [Images demo](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/images.html) sometimes (which doesn't use Infinite Scroll).

Has anyone else experienced this, or know of a solution? As things stand, I won't be able to go ahead with my current project as it's essentially unusable under IE.

BTW - I am using IE9.

Comment: What do your Console and Network tabs show when images fail to load?

Comment: The network tab shows 'Aborted' as the Result for those images that fail to load, with no image type, whereas those that successfully load have an image type of image/jpeg and Response of 304.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From doing some further investigation (trial & error), I've determined that the problem appears to occur only when using Masonry.

So now I've switched to [jQuery Wookmark](http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin), which ticks all the boxes for me, and this exhibits none of the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

The images not loading is a known issue in version 2 of the imagesLoaded script used by Masonry. If you update your code to use the latest version 3 script of imagesLoaded, then that will fix the IE image loading issues.

Note you will need to explicitly load the imagesloaded.js file directly after the masonry js file since previous versions of imagesloaded was included with Masonry but it has now been separated in version 3.

By including the latest imagesloaded.js file, you can keep the existing masonry version, since some options and events of version 3 of masonry has changed and you might find it no longer works as expected.

Download the latest version here: http://desandro.github.io/imagesloaded/